# Adding "user role" on elementor pro field dynamic tag

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, elementor

i currently work on wordpress and using elementor pro as editor on my frontend.
and i need to add "user role" information to my account profile using "dynamic tag" on elementor, but i dont have any idea how to add "user role" tag to elementor

[image]

[image]

[image]

as you can see on the latest pic number 3, there is no "user role" information. and i need to add "user role" information to that field

Answer (score 1):

Elementor doesn´t deliver a dynamic tag for user role.
So you have to create your own dynamic tag.
You can look in the elementor-developer-documention how to do this in detail:
https://developers.elementor.com/dynamic-tags/

A tag for user role could look like this:

```
<?php
use ElementorPro\Modules\DynamicTags\Module;

Class UserRole extends \Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Tag {

    public function get_name() {

        return 'dynamic-tags-user-role';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'User role', 'dynamic-tags' );
    }


    public function get_group() {
        return [ Module::SITE_GROUP ];
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ Module::TEXT_CATEGORY ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {

    }

    public function render() {
        $userId = get_current_user_id();

        if ( empty( $userId ) ) {
            return;
        }
        $userInfo = get_userdata( $userId );
        $userRoles = implode( ', ', $userInfo->roles );
        echo $userRoles;
    }

}
```

You now have to register this tag in elementor

```
<?php
add_action( 'elementor/dynamic_tags/register_tags', function( $dynamic_tags ) {
    // Include the Dynamic tag class file
    include_once( 'path/to/dynamic/tag/class/file' );

    // Finally register the tag
    $dynamic_tags->register_tag( 'UserRole' );
} );
```

If you want a ready to use solution, you can install a plugin which delivers this dynamic tag.
Only free plugin for this i know is
https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamictags